# Java: What collection type should I use for this case?

Tags: java, performance, collections, hashmap

*What I need:*

- **Fastest put/remove, this is used alot.**
- **Iteration, also used frequently.**
- Holds an object, e.g. Player. remove should be o(1) **so maybe hashmap?**
- No duplicate keys
- direct get() is never used, mainly **iterating to retrieve data**.`

**I don't worry about memory, I just want the fastest speed possible even if it's at the cost of memory.**

Comment: What properties does the collection require?  Set? List? Map?  Something else?

Comment: @StephenC That's my question, it should have an object of Player in it so I can reference to it in order to update or retrieve information for all players on a given tile. My current Tile class is on the edit2 above.

Comment: You missed the point. My question is what properties / behaviour does your application require.  Does the collection need to ordered or not?  Does it need to support "duplicate" entries or not?  Do you need to do lookup by key ... or not?  The *requirements* determine what kinds of collection are applicable.

Comment: Well that's my bad then but I tried to explain it in my post. I think I went way too in depth in my post which misleaded people letting them think I needed a 2D array.

The ONLY thing it needs to do is, iterate through, put and remove on location change. It doesn't need to be ordered and there may be no duplicate entries but I solved that one already.

Answer (score 1):

For iteration, nothing is faster than a plain old array. Entries are saved sequentially in memory, so the JVM can get to the next entry simply by adding the length of one entry to the its address.

Arrays are typically a bit of a hassle to deal with compared to maps or lists (e.g: no dictionary-style lookups, fixed length). However, in your case I think it makes sense to go with a one or two dimensional array since the length of the array will not change and dictionary-style lookups are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you correctly you want to have a two-dimensional grid that holds information of which, if any, player is in specific tiles? To me it doesn't sound like you should be removing, or adding things to the grid. I would simply use a two-dimensional array that holds type Player or something similar. Then if no player is in a tile you can set that position to null, or some static value like Player.none() or Tile.empty() or however you'd want to implement it. Either way, a simple two-dimensional array should work fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

The best Collection for your case is a LinkedList.  Linked lists will allow for fast iteration, and fast removal and addition at any place in the linked list.  For example, if you use an ArrayList, and you can to insert something at index i, then you have to move all the elements from i to the end one entry to the right.  The same would happen if you want to remove.  In a linked list you can add and remove in constant time.

Since you need two dimensions, you can use linked lists inside of linked lists:

```
List<List<Tile> players = new LinkedList<List<Tile>>(20);
for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i){
   List<Tile> tiles = new LinkedList<Tile>(20); 

   for (int j = 0; j < 20; ++j){
       tiles.add(new Tile());
   }   

   players.add(tiles);
}
```

Comment: This isn't directly the way where the implementation would suffice for my system. But I think it's in the right direction, I could use this for 'activePlayerTiles' where tiles get added onto another list if the tile is active(a player is on it) which eliminates redundant empty tile checks.

Although is direct-referencing possible when e.g. I want to remove a player(which you described as a tile, you misunderstood my post) from the activePlayerTiles. It's good but has some side-effects too where the activePlayerTiles would be bad if you had alot of activePlayersTiles(1000+)

Answer (score 0):

use a map of sets guarantee O(1) for vertices lookup and amortized O(1) complexity edge insertion and deletions.

```
HashMap<VertexT, HashSet<EdgeT>> incidenceMap;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple one-size-fits-all solution to this.

For example, if you *only* want to append, iterate and use `Iterator.remove()`, there are two obvious options: `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`

- `ArrayList` uses less memory, but `Iterator.remove()` is `O(N)`
- `LinkedList` uses more memory, but `Iterator.remove()` is `O(1)`

If you also want to do fast lookup; (e.g. `Collection.contains` tests), or removal using `Collection.remove`, then `HashSet` is going to be better ... if the collections are likely to be large.  A `HashSet` won't allow you to put an object into the collection multiple times, but that could be an advantage.  It also uses more memory than either `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`.

If you were more specific on the properties required, and what you are optimizing for (speed, memory use, both?) then we could give you better advice.

Comment: Thanks for the nice feedback, my system doesn't remove whilst looping over it so iterator.remove() isnt suited. 

I edited my post since it contained too much in-depth information which confused people. It's straight-forward now.

Answer (score 0):

The requirement of not allowing duplicates is effectively adding a requirement for efficient get().

Your options are either hash-based, or O(Log(N)). Most likely, hashcode will be faster, unless for whatever reason, calling hashCode() + equals() once is much slower than calling compareTo() Log(N) times. This could be, for instance, if you're dealing with very long strings. Log(N) is not very much, by the way: Log(1,000,000,000) ~= 30.

If you want to use a hash-based data structure, then HashSet is your friend. Make sure that Player has a good fast implementation of hashCode(). If you know the number of entries ahead of time, specify the HashSet size. ( ceil(N/load_factor)+1. The default load factor is 0.75).

If you want to use a sort-based structure, implement an efficient Player.compareTo(). Your choices are TreeSet, or Skip List. They're pretty comparable in terms of characteristics. TreeSet is nice in that it's available out of the box in the JDK, whereas only a concurrent SkipList is available. Both need to be rebalanced as you add data, which may take time, and I don't know how to predict which will be better.